# How to I mask out the black from a GeoTIFF

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity

New to Google Earth Engine and I'm wondering why my GeoTIFF's come convert the alpha/transparency of the image to black.  I have these weird black outlines from my TIFF files.

See Screen shot.

[image]

This is orthomosaic from drone data and this is what the TIFF looks like in photoshop.

[image]

Comment: It's not alpha channel you're seeing, but NODATA.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. almost everything that uses transparency tiff, png usually get filter out in various programs and apps.  How would I go about making sure I dont have all that black around the image in google earth engine?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the black colors because you may not have set the appropriate mask when you imported the image.
When you upload the GeoTiff, select the appropriate option (screenshot below):

1. If there is no-data value, use no-data value and input the value to be interpreted as no-data
2. If you have a 4th alpha band, choose that option

[image]